# Defining Routes in Separate Component - React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am new to react and is learning at the moment. I am facing an issue with react-router.

I have routes defined in my app.js as below

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import AdminLogin from "./Admin/Login/index";
import { PrivateRoute } from "../Shared/PrivateRoute";
import Dashboard from "./Admin/Dashboard";

export default class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
        <Route path="/auth/adminlogin" exact={true} component={AdminLogin} />
        <PrivateRoute
          path="/admin/dashboard"
          exact={true}
          component={Dashboard}
        />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

I use the above like below

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import Routes from "./Components/Pages/Routes";
import { AuthProvider } from "./Context/AuthContext";

const styles = {
  noPadding: {
    padding: "0"
  }
};
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AuthProvider>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Navbar />
          <div className="container-fluid" style={styles.noPadding}>
            <Routes />
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      </AuthProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now after login I move to my Dashboard page and over there I have defined some Dashboard routes. Below is my Dashboard Component

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DashboardSidebar from "./DashboardSidebar";
import DashboardRoutes from "./DashboardRoutes";
class Dashboard extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-2">
            <DashboardSidebar />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-10">
            <DashboardRoutes />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

And below are the Dashboard Routes

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MyImages from "./MyImages/index";
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { PrivateRoute } from "../../../Shared/PrivateRoute";
import Orders from "./Orders";
import Reviews from "./Reviews/index";
class DashboardRoutes extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/admin/dashboard"
            exact={true}
            component={MyImages}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/admin/dashboard/orders"
            exact={true}
            component={Orders}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/admin/dashboard/reviews"
            exact={true}
            component={Reviews}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DashboardRoutes;
```

In above MyImages component loads fine but not the other dashboard components. Kindly suggest what is wrong or we need to define all routes at the same place in order to achieve this.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an exact={true} on the path to Dashboard and hence no nested path will match correctly, You need to Remove exact attribute from Routes that have nested Routes and Reoreder them within Switch components

```
 <PrivateRoute
      path="/admin/dashboard"
      component={Dashboard}
    />
```

Entire Solution

App.js

```
export default class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
        <Route path="/auth/adminlogin" exact={true} component={AdminLogin} />
        <PrivateRoute
          path="/admin/dashboard"
          component={Dashboard}
        />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

Dashboard Routes

```
class DashboardRoutes extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/admin/dashboard"
            exact={true}
            component={MyImages}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/admin/dashboard/orders"
            exact={true}
            component={Orders}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/admin/dashboard/reviews"
            exact={true}
            component={Reviews}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DashboardRoutes;
```

In case the DashboardRoutes also have nested children, its better to configure your Routes like

```
class DashboardRoutes extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/admin/dashboard/orders"
            component={Orders}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/admin/dashboard/reviews"
            component={Reviews}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/admin/dashboard"
            component={MyImages}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DashboardRoutes;
```